# Was it formerly illegal for a woman to be president of the United States?

Tags: united-states, discrimination, president, public-office

Was there some statute or other law a century ago that said only males could serve as president?  If so, when did that change (if in fact it did)?

Comment: There's some analysis in [this article](http://www.usnews.com/news/articles/2015/10/30/are-women-allowed-to-be-president).  The conclusion seems to be "language is ambiguous and no court has ruled on the question".  The question was probably more difficult before the passage of the Nineteenth Amendment granting female suffrage; but in regard to your original question, the Nineteenth Amendment was ratified a few weeks *before* Wilson's stroke.

Comment: @NateEldredge : From the article it appears that there was never a law that said a woman couldn't be president. The Constitution says "he" shall serve a four-year term and "he" shall have this power and that power, and "he" shall be at least 35 years old. BUT the framers did NOT always intend "he" to mean a male: they wrote "A Person charged in any State with [a] Crime, who shall flee from Justice, and be found in another State, shall on Demand of the executive Authority of the State from which ___he___ fled, be delivered up..." They cannot have intended to exempt women.

Comment: Well, as the article makes clear, scholars are divided as to what the framers intended, or how a court would have ruled had the issue been raised at various points in history.  Your argument makes sense to me, but I certainly can't claim to be any expert.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The language argument about the constitution is that the Constitution uses the pronoun "he" in referring to the president – they would not have used the construction "he or she", or "s/he". Article I also uses "he" to refer to qualifications of representatives and senators (residency, age). Then in creating the office of predident pro tempore of the Senate, it uses "he" to refer to a Vice President who is exercising the office of President of the United States. In Article IV Section II it states:

> A person charged in any state with treason, felony, or other crime,
>   who shall flee from justice, and be found in another state, shall on
>   demand of the executive authority of the state from which **he** fled,
>   be delivered up, to be removed to the state having jurisdiction of the
>   crime.

Thus women cannot be extradited, if the "'he' means male" theory prevails.

In 1872, [Victoria Woodhull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_Woodhull#Presidential_candidate) ran for president, and while it is true there were questions about her eligibility, that was because of her age rather than sex. [Belva Lockwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belva_Ann_Lockwood#Political_career) ran for president in 1884 and 1888. This is not strong enough to constitute proof that being female was not a bar to holding the office, but it is indicative of that conclusion. The strongest evidence that the use of "he" in the Constitution had no significance is the fact that [Jeanette Rankin](http://history.house.gov/People/Listing/R/RANKIN,-Jeannette-(R000055)/) was elected US Representative from Montana in 1916, 2 years before Congress approved the 19th Amendment.

Since the only way to impose any restrictions on the presidency is via the Constitution (i.e. Congress can't pass a law redefining the qualification for office), and since the use of "he" has never been strictly interpreted to preclude female senators and representatives, we have to conclude that there never has been a prohibition against a female president.

Comment: I think 1916 is when Jeanette Rankin was elected.  But I don't know whether the state of Montana allowed women to vote at that time.  Do you?

Comment: You're right, I corrected that. They did have the vote in Montana in 1914 which no doubt aided her election.

Comment: "Congress can't pass a law redefining the qualification for office".  I wonder about that.  Certainly Congress can't validly pass a law saying someone under 35 or someone who's not a citizen can be president.  But what if they passed a law saying the president must be at least 36 years old?

Comment: That would almost certainly also be found unconstitutional. If the legislature can pass laws tightening the requirements of the office, then they can select the president outright by tightening the requirements so much that they bar any other feasible candidate. Broadly, the constitution makes it clear that the states select the president, and that the legislature's capacity to interfere is in reaction to specific failures on case-by-case basis: they break ties and prosecute impeachments.

Answer (score -1):

The first lady is **not** part of the legal line succession for presidency in the United States, and she **never** has been. Throwing in Wilson and suffrage is all relatively moot. There's no need for any "formal" statute which states *specifically* that one single individual is ineligible.

The gender of the president's spouse has little to do with anything. The First Lady is **not** a formally elected nor appointed government official and therefore ineligible. The US could have a female president and the "first man" would be equally ineligible.

[US Presidential line of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_line_of_succession)

> 1 Vice President
>   2 Speaker of the House of Representatives
>   3 President pro tempore of the Senate
>   4 Secretary of State
>   5 Secretary of the Treasury
>   6 Secretary of Defense
>   7 Attorney General
>   — Secretary of the Interior 
>   8 Secretary of Agriculture
>   9 Secretary of Commerce 
>   10 Secretary of Labor
>   11 Secretary of Health and Human Services
>   12 Secretary of Housing and Urban Development
>   13 Secretary of Transportation
>   14 Secretary of Energy
>   15 Secretary of Education
>   16 Secretary of Veterans Affairs
>   17 Secretary of Homeland Security

Comment: This also doesn't answer the question. The question is was it formerly illegal for a woman to be president, not can the First Lady become president

Comment: Question was edited (several times) apparently as I posted.

Comment: Nope, question was always "Was it formerly illegal for a woman to be president of the United States?" Per the edit history. I believe the example given may have confused you.

Comment: @DaleM... sigh.. if you know Stack.. you know that first 1-2 minute edits aren't shown in the edit history. But okay.  Yeah sure.. I'm at fault. It's damn unfriendly around here. (Those last two *original* questions that are crossed out were **not** part of the post originally.)

Comment: Huh? Scott? What just happened? Judging by the comments I see, you're being pretty unfriendly. If someone makes note of something that doesn't address a question, you should respond to that, and improve your answer to specifically address it, not start an argument in the comments.

Comment: I suppose nit-picking in comments is to be expected in [Law.se], but yes, let's all strive to keep it collegial.

Comment: This answers the original question, which was "A comment under the article said she [the first lady] would have been legally forbidden to actually be president at that time. Is that true?"

Comment: The statements made in this answer are accurate, but I think they are based on a misreading of the question. As far as I can see from the edit history, the question never asked "could Mrs Wilson" have become president in place of her husband?", but rather "at the time of the Wilson Presidency, or earlier, were women barred from that office?" This answer does not seem to me to address that issue.

Comment: @DavidSiegel the question was **not** misread. The question was **edited** *after* I posed an answer. See the comment above yours by David Schwartz for the **original** question.

Comment: @Scott, I have read the entire editing history. But the present answer does not seem to me to answer the question as described in the Schwartz comment. I would add that the current Presidential Succession act was not, unless I am mistaken, in force during the Wilson Presidency. The succession law then was different, although it did not include the President's spouse any more than it does now.